# Implementing 'sliding' pagination

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, pagination, vuejs3

I'm attempting to implement pagination with "sliding" behavior. I want to display a maximum of 4 pages (regardless of window width, so that all 100+ pages won't show up on mobile screen), and when, for instance, pages 1, 2, 3, 4 are visible, if I'm on page 4 and click the "next" button, the visible pages should shift to 2, 3, 4, 5. Also, on full screen I want to display 3 list items, then when I reduce the window width, I want to display 2 and finally 1 on mobile screens. Currently, clicking the "next" button doesn't produce any effect. Here's what I've tried so far:

Template:

```
// pagination list
<ul class="pagination__list">
    <li class="pagination__item">
        <router-link
            :to="{
                query: {
                    page: pageNumber,
                },
            }"
            class="pagination__link"
            v-for="pageNumber in totalPages"
            :key="pageNumber"
            :class="{ active: pageNumber === page.number }">
            {{ pageNumber }}
        </router-link>
    </li>
</ul>

// next btn
<router-link
    :to="{
        query: {
            page: nextPage,
        },
    }"
    class="pagination__btn-next"
    :class="{ inactive: page.number === totalPages }">Link
</router-link>
```

Script:

```
<script setup>
import { onMounted, reactive, computed, watch } from 'vue';
import { useStoreRecipe } from '@/store/storeRecipe';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

const route = useRoute();
const storeRecipe = useStoreRecipe();

const page = reactive({
    number: computed(() => parseInt(route.query.page) || 1),
    size: 3,
});

const totalPages = computed(() => {
    return Math.ceil(storeRecipe.recipesCount / page.size);
});

const startPage = computed(() => Math.max(page.number, 1));
const endPage = computed(() => Math.min(startPage.value + 3, totalPages.value));

const nextPage = () => {
    if (endPage.value < totalPages.value) {
        startPage.value++;
        endPage.value++;
};

const prevPage = () => {
    if (startPage.value > 1) {
        startPage.value--;
        endPage.value--;
    }
};


// ... fetching recipes
</script>
```

Server:

```
if (page && pageSize) {
const offset = (page - 1) * pageSize;
const recipes = await pool.query(
    'SELECT * FROM recipe ORDER BY recipe_id LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2',
    [pageSize, offset]
);
res.json(recipes.rows);
}
```

I'm looking for a possible solution.

Comment: Maybe, you need to add 'path' param to the router-link.to.